# Twitter Bootstrap - Open and close div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Twitter Bootstrap framework. I would like to open and close a div from a button.  How to do that?

Thanks
Uli

Comment: That has got absolutely nothing to do with Bootstrap.

Comment: There a lot of built in components and my thought was I overlooked this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is covered explicitly in the [bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse).

There is no JS needed (other than including the bootstrap JS.) Everything is done via data attributes.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
  simple collapsible
</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse in"> collapse </div>​
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3UubF/

Comment: Sorry, it's me again. Is there a way to scroll the div also into view? (To the top of the page)

Comment: try putting `href="#demo"` (or whatever id you used) on the button.

Comment: Still not jumping to the top. My button: `<button type="button" href="#contact" class="btn btn-default btn-medium" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#contact">Contact</button>` Anything wrong with it?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that looks like your page?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean show and hide? If so, I'd just use jQuery. It's Bootstrap's js framework of choice. I'd do something like this...

```
<a class="btn" id="togglemydiv">My Button</a>

$('#togglemydiv').on('click', function()   { $('#targetdiv').toggleClass('hide'); });
```